# DB2 Datasource in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, db2, ssrs-2008

I have to connect to Db2 data source from SSRS and create reports.I installed latest Db2 client on my system.

While adding datasources in SSRS I selected "OLEDB" Datasource and then "IBM OLEDB Provider", after entering the servername,Username,pwd...it throws an error saying..

> The database alias couldn't be found in db2dsdriver.cfg 
>   configuration file.

Can some one point me in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM documentation on that particular file can be found [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/c0054555.html).  It explains what it is, and explains how to edit it.

Essentially, you'll need to edit the file on your Report Server and add the server name.

Exerpt:

> The db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file can be edited. However, the
>   file must be edited manually. In addition, after editing the file, you
>   must restart the application for the changes to take effect. The
>   configuration file is created in one of the following paths:  for a
>   data server client, the configuration file is created in a folder
>   named cfg under the instance path:
>
> - On AIX®, HP-UX, Linux, or Solaris operating systems, instance_path/cfg
> - On Windows operating systems, instance_path\cfg
>
> for a data server driver, the configuration file is created in a
>   folder named cfg under the installation path:
>
> - On AIX, HP-UX, Linux, or Solaris operating systems, installation_path/cfg
> - On Windows operating systems, installation_path\cfg
>
> A sample configuration file is shipped to help you get started. It is
>   located in the sqllib/cfg directory. The configuration file contains
>   the following sections:
>
> - the data source name section contained within the DSN_Collection tags,
> - the database information section contained within the databases tags,
> - the global attributes section contained within the parameters tags.

```
<configuration>
    <DSN_Collection>
        <dsn alias="alias1" name="name1" host="server1.net1.com" port="50001"/>
        <!-- Long aliases are supported -->
        <dsn alias="longaliasname2" name="name2" host="server2.net1.com" port="55551">
            <parameter name="Authentication" value="Client"/>
        </dsn>
    </DSN_Collection>
    <databases>
        <database name="name1" host="server1.net1.com" port="50001">
            <parameter name="CurrentSchema" value="OWNER1"/>
            <WLB>
                <parameter name="enableWLB" value="true"/>
                <parameter name="maxTransports" value="50"/>
            </WLB>
            <ACR>
                <parameter name="enableACR" value="true"/>
            </ACR>
        </database>
        <!-- Local IPC connection -->
        <database name="name3" host="localhost" port="0">
            <parameter name="IPCInstance" value="DB2"/>
            <parameter name="CommProtocol" value="IPC"/>
        </database>
    </databases>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="GlobalParam" value="Value"/>
    </parameters>
</configuration>
```